# Link some users to a content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a content type called "Event". For each event, I would like to be able to specify contacts (people in charge of organising).

Therefore I would like to add a field "Contact" to the Event type, where a widget would give access to the list of users. One could then pick one or several users.

This field would be displayed as a list of links to the profiles of those users.

I seem to remember there was a module providing that widget in Drupal 6, but I am now using Drupal 7, and haven't been able to find the necessary module!

Thanks!

(NB: I'm not using the Event module, but Date + Calendar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible options you can check out:

[**Entity Reference module**](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) - can reference user entities

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

[**Relation module**](http://drupal.org/project/Relation)

> Relation is an API module and storage model for both simple and the
>   most complex relations between entities. The module can handle both
>   directional and symmetrical relations very well.

Comment: Thanks, I used the Entity Reference module, just what I needed!